# Type small caps, raised text in Latex

Tags: typewriter

I want to write the string "Uppaal" in Latex in this form: [image]

How can i made it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following command could solve it:

```
\def\uppaal{\raisebox{.5ex}{\scshape Uppaal}}
```

and use `\uppaal` wherever required.